# Write a cpprestsdk json value object into a file

Tags: c++, json, rest, cpprest-sdk

I receive a `JSON` response body as part of a REST request. I would like to write the body of the `JSON` into a file. A quick way to do this would be to use the `web::http::response` object itself..

```
pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("testResults.json")).then([=](ostream outFile)
    {
        *fileStream = outFile;
//some work
    })
.then([=](http_response response)
    {
        printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());

        // Write response body into the file.
        return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
    })
    .then([=](size_t s)
    {
        return fileStream->close();
    });
```

However, after receiving the response body, I extract the `JSON` from it to calculate some values, after which, as documented, the `json` cannot be extracted or used again from the `response` body, so i have to use the `web::json::value` object.

```
http::json::value someValue = response.extract_json().get();
```

I'd like to write this `json::value` object, `someValue`, to a `JSON` file, but not sure how to get it done. Writing to an `ostream` object with `serialize.c_cstr()` on `someValue` gives weird output.

```
ostream o("someFile.json"); 
o << setw(4) << someValue.serialize().c_str() << std<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your system typdef std::string as a wide string, then outputting via ostream would lead to weird output.

`web::json::value::serialize()` returns a `utility::string_t`

https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1json_1_1value.html#a5bbd4bca7b13cd912ffe76af825b0c6c

`utility::string_t` is typedef as a `std::string`

https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaceutility.html#typedef-members

So something like this would work:

```
std::filesystem::path filePath(L"c:\\someFile.json"); // Assuming wide chars here. Could be U instead of L depending on your setup
std::wofstream outputFile(filePath);
outputFile << someJSONValue.serialize().c_str();
outputFile.close();
```